# Solutions to 'Statistical Learning with Sparsity'

Tags: self-study, references, lasso, teaching, checking

I've recently been working through *Statistical Learning with Sparsity* (SLS) by Hastie, Tibshirani and Hastie.

I found some exercises very hard, and think I found some mistakes. A set of solutions would be very helpful.

I've recently discovered that *Elements of Statistical Learning* now has a manual of notes and solutions by [John Weatherwax](https://waxworksmath.com/Authors/G_M/Hastie/hastie.html).

Does anyone know of something similar for SLS? (no luck with google)

If not, I'd be happy to share the solutions to the questions I've attempted. Is there a standard protocol to start a collaborative solution manual?
(or wiki/alternative place for discussion)
(and is it safe to assume the authors won't mind?)

Comment: What's wrong with the process of asking questions here on Cross Validated, with the `self-study` tag?

Comment: Just that it feels better to me to have a more coherent whole; and would be more efficient if there was sufficient interest in the resource